# Printing background-image of an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have this offer page:
http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/offer/hvac/

On `:hover` the boxes with offered items have an option to print, however it seems i can't actually output it onto document.

Here's my JS:

```
$(".print").click(function() {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    $title = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find("h3").text();
    $bgimg = $(this).parent().parent().parent().css("background-image");
    $img = "<img src='$bgimg' width='100%'/>";
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + $title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write($img);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
  });
```

How may i achieve the result? `Background-image` is attached to `.relative-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari */
    color-adjust: exact !important;                 /*Firefox*/
}
```

Try to append this CSS into the window. It's working in Chrome and Firefox, not sure about IE.